# Using HTML2Canvas with multiple text shadows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I've done a lot of Googling, and it seems to me that the only way to capture HTML into a picture is by using HTML2Canvas. This has worked for me in the past but it seems that HTML2Canvas doesn't support multiple `text-shadows`, which is very frustrating because that is exactly what I need at the moment.

Here is a random JSFiddle example (not my code): https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3386/

As you can see by the text `Age` there are 2 `text-shadows`, however, when you click for a PNG the image only shows up with the first `text-shadow`. This is a known issue, but one that hasn't been solved yet as far as I can tell.

Is there any work around? I really need multiple `text-shadows`...

Comment: Create elements by each text shadow that you want, and position them with absolute positioning

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes I ended up doing this and it seems to work fine. Thanks!